# Icon shine problems with the LARGE 512 icon

Tags: iphone, icons, itunes, app-store-connect

I am registering a new version of my app in iTunes Connect, now I have to upload the large 512*512 icon, when I uploaded it everything looked fine. A few days later, iTunes Connect has added the "Icon shine effect" to it how can I remove it?
Please note that this has nothing to do with the .plist file and "Icon already includes gloss effect" because I haven't even uploaded the binary yet, the problem is with the large icon solely.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you will upload binary with appropriate flag informing about that gloss effect is off, the icon in iTunes Connect will be updated! Don't worry about this.